# Is there a word for "The one who walks like a deer/stag"

Tags: phrase-requests

I want to describe the walking style of character in a story of mine. Is there any such word for describing the walking style of a deer ?

Comment: You mean *quadruped*?

Comment: to walk in a deer-like manner or walk like a deer. We often forget that useful use of like....deer move gracefully and slowly, when grazing.

Comment: I can't provide any single word or phrase. But a [post](https://www.fieldandstream.com/articles/hunting/2013/11/how-still-hunt-and-stalk-deer) in Field & Stream says that "a deer . . . after putting a front hoof down immediately follows with the opposite back hoof, in a step-step, pause, step-step cadence."

Comment: Lambie's *graceful* works. There's also *sure footed*. But it's unclear what kind of deer-like manner you're describing. The term you seek would depend on the specifics. Please [edit] your question to describe what you're looking for.

Comment: Avoid word/phrase requests that lack: (i) objective criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They [stride](https://www.etsy.com/listing/551913946/striding-stag-mounted-limited-edition?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=deer%20strider&ref=sr_gallery-1-3), very confidently. (Artwork titled *Striding Stag*, thanks to Etsy.com). From the *Free Dictionary*:

> Stride: 1. walk with long, decisive steps in a specified direction.

Comment: The deer in my neck of the woods aren't so confident....:)

Comment: What do you think that has to do with deer?